# HTML IMG: What is the benefit of setting an explicit width and height attribute within the HTML markup?

Tags: html, css, image

What is the benefit of explicitly defining a width and height attribute for an IMG element? I can set width to 100% via CSS and unless I explicitly set the height via CSS then the image element will retain the intrinsic aspect ratio. Conversely I can define a width and height attribute in the HTML markup and omit the CSS declaration and the image will just render at those explicit dimensions. Why set the dims in HTML if you are going to subsequently set width to 100% via CSS?

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because the question pointed to as a duplicate has answers which are out of date.

Comment: @AHaworth So what's stopping anyone posting up-to-date answers on that question?

Comment: @AHaworth what do you mean by "out of date"?

Comment: @AdrianMole of course people can post an uptodate answer on that question, but how would they find it once this question is closed as this question wont be seen by many people. So we lose the possibility of others critiquing any new answer.

Comment: @NicoHaase by out of date I didn’t mean incorrect, I meant not uptodate - they don’t give a full answer to the question as of today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and height attributes have been given a new lease of life - they can be set and subsequently used to set the CSS aspect-ratio of the replaced element. This helps avoid problems the browser has of sizing things before they are loaded.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/images/aspect_ratio_mapping) for a fuller explanation, in particular:

> This article explains a change that has occurred in the way sizes are worked out on web documents when width and height attributes are set on them.
>
> This change means that the aspect ratio of the image is calculated by
> the browser early on and can then be used to correct the size needed
> to display the image before it has loaded

You can set the aspect ratio in CSS by:

```
aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have a better answer, but perhaps to provide more functionality... you can still use object-fit as I understand to retain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Google recommend to set image size to avoid CLS (Cumulative Layout Shift). Read more https://web.dev/cls/